# Reusable modals in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following popup modal:

```
<div class="modal-wrapper" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-popup-margin">
        <div class="modal-popup">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close close-modal">×</button>
                <span class="modal-title">Change Password</span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                     <span class="label">Old Password</span>
                     <input class="Textinput form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid old-password ng-invalid-required" value="" type="password" name="oldPassword" />
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                     <span class="label">New Password</span>
                     <input class="Textinput form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid new-password ng-invalid-required" value="" type="password" name="newPassword" />
                </div>
                <div class="row error-row">
                     <span class="label">&nbsp;</span>
                     <span class="error-message"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit">SAVE</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default-flat-goog pull-right close-modal">CANCEL</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-backdrop close-modal"></div>
</div>
```

It is meant to be re-usable, in that I would define the following for each item that calls it:

- The name or the button(s) that are included in the `modal-footer`.
- The various fields in the modal body, everything that is now a `row`.
- The name of the modal, in `modal-title`.
- The `url` the form submits to on clicking the `SAVE` button.

How would I create a "re-usable" form here without copy-pasting this same modal into each template and re-writing the changeable parts of it?

Comment: The key is in the content of the #modal-title, #modal-body and #modal-footer elements. You want to dynamically change those areas of HTML. Now, try to code something and come back with what you come up with and we can help from there.

Comment: What JavaScript/jQuery have you tried? A [mcve] would be more helpful

Comment: @David542 Look [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WayeOd?editors=0010)

Comment: If someone asked me to build this today I would use the React framework. Vanilla javascript and html weren't designed well for this. jQuery was great for a while but there are cleaner and more efficient ways of handling this in modern frameworks. You may also want to consider Vue or Angular (I've used both and still prefer React).

Comment: I just quickly read your question, but are you looking for the `template` element?

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, I would suggest injecting HTML with javascript, if you don't want to use frameworks. Your html inside a very basic builder function:

```
function makeModal(buttonshtml, bodyhtml, title, saveurl){
  return `<div class="modal-wrapper" style="display: block;">
<div class="modal-popup-margin">
    <div class="modal-popup">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close close-modal">×</button>
            <span class="modal-title">${title}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            ${bodyhtml}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            ${buttonshtml}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-backdrop close-modal"></div>
</div>`
}
```

However, I don't see any save button or form.